# Ampps keep showing blank pages

Tags: apache-http-server, php, ampps

This same problem was address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361789/how-to-fix-ampps-showing-blank-page#_=_) but the problem didn't cover everything. Because in my own case I can't access this even this http://localhost/ampps/.

I have tried everything I can, but not working. Uninstalled and install several times, clean the system and did every possible troubleshooting I can do but not working as expected. 
How do I make this blank page to go away? I fear resetting my system may be the only possible solution, please help

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it, by cleaning all the registry entries for Ampps, deleting anything that has ampps in it and then reinstall ampps again.